# How can Nami's punches hurt Luffy so much?

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece anime, there are many instances where Nami has beaten Luffy to a horrible state,

| Episode # | Screenshot |
| --- | --- |
| Episode 215 | [image] |
| Episode 316 | [image] |
| Episode 572 | [image] |

and maybe many more.

How is she able to do it? Does she know how to use Haki?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another answer, also on [SBS](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_43)

> D: Blows shouldn't hurt Luffy, so why does he get bruises and swelling when Nami and the others beat the crap out of him?! Tell me!!! P.N. Zororin Love
>
> O: When the crew beats up on each other, it's always in admonishment with a strong sense of purpose, which is why it works so well!! It works on his spirit!! I bet Nami is thinking, "It's his spirit that hurts deep down!!" ...right? I guess not.

So Nami and others didn't punch Luffy physically, but they hurt his spirit, and with doing so, his body also get hurts

> right? I guess not.

I think Oda doesn't really want to give any logical answer here

Answer (score 9):

It's most likely some kind of "Fist of Love" like when Luffy's crew met Garp for the first time. Garp suddenly punch Luffy, and he's not using Haki, base on [this SBS question](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_62)

> D: In Volume 45 when Garp punched Luffy, why did it work? Was it Haki after all? Or was it "Love"? P.N. Mori-san
>
> O: It is "Love" in this case.

[image]
[image]

Comment: then how would you explain [this](http://lookpic.com/O/i2/601/S4vaWd9g.png) incident in [episode 158](http://www.watchonepiece.us/one-piece-episode-158-english-sub/) when Luffy was beaten by Sanji on Skypiea for requesting a different gondola?

Comment: I give another answer here, I think both reason are the same, and Love Punch basically also hurt Luffy's spirit, but since it's only my opinion I leave it to you to choose what's the best answer

Comment: @AbhilashK the point is, none of them know how to use haki at that time, maybe some of them gain haki power after timeskip but before that, not even luffy has it. (luffy had it but he can't control it)

Comment: I disagree with all of you. Nami's Haki (Fist of Love for Life) is one of the first ones shown in the anime. Episode 32, minute 12:00. Watch the "steam" come of Zoro's back.

Answer (score 7):

It's a combination of cartoonish silliness and the fact that Luffy's really not defending against them.

Comment: sources to back this up....

Answer (score 0):

In manga chapter 1058, we can see Nami is using Conqueror Haki while punishing Luffy.

> [image]

I think that Luffy's Devil Fruit is full of imagination. Whatever he imagines, he can do it, because the Sun God Nika DF's ability is the most ridiculous power in One Piece.

So, what I am telling is that if Luffy wants to imagine that Garp and Nami's fist hurts, so it hurts Luffy. And in the next panel in chapter 1058, Luffy imagines Nami using Conqueror Haki, so that's why she can even use Conqueror Haki even though Jimbei mentioned that's a king's Haki.